# Add parameters on href url with javascript and with specific conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problem with my `javascript` functions. I want to add some parameters to the `href` url when it cliked. For example I want to add `?param=1` in `href` url when it's clicked. But before add some parameters I want to check if the url in `href` is **http://example.com** and that parameters not contain `?param=1`. After it checked and the url is **http://example.com** and not contain `?param=1`, I want to add the `?param=1` in that url. Why I want to check first before adding the parameters? It's because I don't want to add the parameters in any url but just in specific url which I want.

This is what I do till now:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + "?param=1";
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​
```

But, I don't know how to check and make specific conditions if the `href` is **http://example.com**. Please anybody know how to do this could help me. Thanks before.

Comment: You can use this logic to check if values exist in the querystring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(href);
    if(href) {
        if(href.indexOf("param=1")==-1){
          href = href + "?param=1";
          console.log(href);
         // location.href = href;       
         }else{
          href = href + "?param=2";
          console.log(href);
         // location.href = href;
        }
     //   
       
    }
});
```

```html
<a href="http:example.com?param=1">click</a>
```

The index to start the search in the string or object. It will return -1 if there is no search found.

Comment: @Antonio window.location.href returns the href (URL) of the current page
window.location.hostname returns the domain name of the web host
window.location.pathname returns the path and filename of the current page
window.location.protocol returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)
window.location.assign loads a new document

Comment: @Antonio You can simply split the string using `?` symbol `var domain=url.split('?')[0];`

Comment: It works. But if I delete `e.preventDefault();` why it open the link without `?param` ?

Comment: @Antonio  It will prevent the default behavior click on `<a href` . You can programmatically redirect browser using `location.href`

Answer (score 0):

Check the queryString and see if it has the `param1` value, if it does not then append it.

```
var url = new URL("http://www.example.com?param=1"); //window.location.href

if (url.searchParams.get('param'))
{
  console.log("Param exists");
}
else
{
   console.log("Param does not exist")
   url + "?param=1"
   console.log(url);
}
```

Comment: `url.split("?")[1]` that is just check in index 1 but how if the param not in index 1 ?

Comment: @Antonio you may try this one now!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var href = "www.example.com?param=1";
    if(href.indexOf("www.example.com") >=0 && href.indexOf("param=1") >= 0) {
        alert('Url has given words');
        //location.href = href + "?param=1";
       // e.preventDefault();
    }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Check URL</div>
```

Comment: `href.indexOf("example.com")` you can add any part of a word to check against the provided string.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        console.log(href.includes('?param=1')); 
        // You can do whatever you want based on this condition
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<a href='http://example.com/'>Link 1</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/?param=1'>Link 2</a>
```

Comment: href.includes(' example.com') - this will return true or false

Answer (score -1):

Learn about indexOf for check if values exist in the querystring

```js
var str="Hello world!"
document.write(str.indexOf("Hello") + "<br />")
document.write(str.indexOf("World") + "<br />")
document.write(str.indexOf("world"))
```

- The indexOf () method is sensitive to case sensitive.
- If the string value that is to be retrieved does not appear, the
  method returns -1

Comment: Could you give me the example please ?